# Mail() error when adding bbc

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a mailing script to send emails to specific users. I get the emails from a mysql database.

The email setup is working fine when sending the email to a single person. when just using to: and no bcc:

But when I insert the line with bbc: I get an error :

```
$headers .= "Bcc: ". implode(", ", $recipients) ."\r\n"; <-- Error happens here
```

i have tried both removing space in implode and checked all emails. They are all valid seperated by comma

Also i tried to insert: error_get_last() and the error returns no valuables. The array is empty. So i really cant see where the error should be.

My code is:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE receive_email = 1") 
or die(mysqli_error());

/* Details for emails */
$name = "domain.com";
$email = "info@domain.com" ;
/* End of details */

$recipients = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $recipients[] = $row["email"];
}

$to .= "info@domain.com";

$subject .= "Domain.com account notification";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $name . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: ". implode(", ", $recipients) ."\r\n"; <-- Error happens here
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 

$message .= '
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Domain.com</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
</body>
</html>
';

$send_email = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if(!$send_email) {   
    echo "Error<br>";
    echo implode(', ', $recipients);
} else {
    echo "Success<br>";
    echo implode(', ', $recipients);
}
```

Comment: $headers .= "Bcc: ". implode(", ", $recipients) ."\r\n"; <-- Error happens here

Comment: **What error do you get?**

Comment: Have you checked your `$recipients` variable, does every element contain a valid e-mail address?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space in the implode ? implode(", ", $recipients) => implode(",", $recipients)

Comment: i've checked both $recipents variables. All emails are valid and followed by a comma and a space. Also tried to delete space. still getting error when using bcc

Comment: I think adding a *BBC* instead of  a *BCC* to a mail might cause some confusion.

Comment: Sry, that an error. its bcc: in the code

Comment: Big Bla.... - oh wait, wrong stack- site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific solution to your issue, but the PHP Mail function is really, REALLY poorly implemented and has various flaws and issues because 'emails' in general are as wide a topic as 'web pages', read some articles from sources such as mailchimp ( http://blog.mailchimp.com/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/ ) which touch on the subject of emails in general and specifically HTML emails, but as well as this there is a wealth of issues around the **email headers** which need to be PERFECTLY right to enable delivery.

It is a huge minefield and if I wasn't such a proud programmer I would often have opted for Mailchimp or similar.

But, there is a solution. Look up PHPMailer ( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer ) and download and install this, I have found it to be 100% effective for my PHP code and delivers the email EVERY time, with clear error description and reporting.

I would qualify this by saying that sending any email - you need to specify a valid FROM server and FROM name/email address.

Good luck

Comment: this sounds like a plug but this is not an advert. I really like PHPMailer. Explore it